# Invoking Listbox in threads

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to have my listbox clear it self at the end of my thread. I am having issues invoking it and was hoping someone would show me how.

```
 public delegate void ClearDelegate(ListBox lb);


        public void ItemClear(ListBox lb)
        {
            if (lb.InvokeRequired)
            {
                lb.Invoke(new ClearDelegate(ItemClear), new Object[] { lb });
            }

            listBox1.Items.Clear();

        }
```

Comment: looks okay, what is the error?

Comment: I think the error is I still don't understand how to use threads correctly. I am going over them now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite trivial example using it's own thread (**attention** just for showing, better here would maybe a `BackgroundWorker`!):

```
private Thread _Thread;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Thread = new Thread(OnThreadStart);
}

private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var state = _Thread.ThreadState;

    switch (state)
    {
        case ThreadState.Unstarted:
            _Thread.Start(listBox1);
            break;
        case ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin:
        case ThreadState.Running:
            _Thread.Suspend();
            break;
        case ThreadState.Suspended:
            _Thread.Resume();
            break;
    }
}

private static void OnThreadStart(object obj)
{
    var listBox = (ListBox)obj;
    var someItems = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(index => "My Item " + index).ToArray();

    foreach (var item in someItems)
    {
        listBox.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox.Items.Add(item)));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    listBox.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox.Items.Clear()));
}
```

Comment: i was getting depreciated errors for _Thread.Resume and _Thread.Suspend
added/changed
ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(true); 
_event.Reset(); and  _event.Set();

Comment: @user2190928: That's one reason for the attention flag.

Comment: Oliver, so could i use  if ((_Thread.ThreadState) == ThreadState.Stopped)
                    MessageBox.Show("done");
                } in my button to have something happen when it is stopped?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
it is enought to put `listBox1.Items.Clear();` statement into `else` statement.

Another thing is that you can use asynchronous method `BeginInvoke` that do not block the thread to wait for method finish.

Answer (score -1):

Listbox can be accessed only by the UI thread and not the worker thread.

```
    var sync = SynchronizatoinContext.Current;

    sync.Post(delegate {
     // Perform UI related changes here
}, null) //as the worker thread cannot access the UI thread resources
```

Comment: Are you sure? What about `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` methods?